# LoopedSlider suddenly stopped working

Tags: javascript

I have been styling a predefined site, and after adding some box-shadows last night my loopedSlider has stopped working.

I have installed a clean version of the template I am using alongside. The page in question is

[scorpionhosting.net](http://scorpionhosting.net)

and the clean template is:

[scorpionhosting.net/cleanhostpay](http://scorpionhosting.net/cleanhostpay)

I've been back through the CSS, checked the html and w3c validated both to double check it wasn't something obvious (closing tags etc). I notice that the clean template is using loopedslider.min.js while my page is not. I don't understand why this is, I'm afraid I don't speak javascript very well yet!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clean version has jQuery 1.3.2 loading:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Your new version has no jQuery.

The latest version of jQuery is 1.9.1, by the way, so I'd update for a new site. You may have trouble with your slider if you go that far, though, since 1.9 removed some deprecated methods. I'd try 1.9.1, and if it doesn't work, try 1.8.3.

Comment: Thanks for that, it turns out this line in the footer:

`<% if(!@cgi.path_info || @cgi.path_info == '/' || @cgi.path_info == '/index') %>`

had been changed to this:

`<% if(@cgi.path_info == '/' || @cgi.path_info == '/index') %>`

Im not exactly sure what it does, PHP is nect on the list after javascript/jquery, but it was stopping jquery loading. I will update jquery next. Thanks isherwood!